# optimilisation of differential equations in Matlab with built-in events

Tags: matlab, events, optimization, ode

I try to optimise the system of differential equations. I work on 'simple' example to get to know where my problem is, so equations are simplified.

I have to pass the external data into the system of equations (variables-different hormone levels on the specific day). I try to do it using events, but my understanding of events is practically none.

After calling a function in Command Window:
cost_dimer([1 1])

I get error messages:

> Error using cost_dimer>@(t,y)ode_dimer_parametric(t,y,E2,P4)
>   Too many input arguments.
>
> Error in odearguments (line 87)
>   f0 = feval(ode,t0,y0,args{:});   % ODE15I sets args{1} to yp0.
>
> Error in ode45 (line 115)
>       odearguments(FcnHandlesUsed, solver_name, ode, tspan, y0, options, varargin);
>
> Error in cost_dimer (line 10)
>       [T, h] = ode45(@(t,y)ode_dimer_parametric(t,y,E2,P4),...

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.
Malgosia

```
     function ydot=ode_dimer_parametric(t,y,p)
     k_1 = p(1);
     k_minus1 = p(2);
     E2=E2; P4=P4;
     S1 = 2 *E2* k_minus1 * y(2)  -  2 * k_1 * y(1)*y(1);
     S2 = k_1 * y(1)*y(1) + P4 -  k_minus1 * y(2);
     ydot = [S1; S2];

     function cost = cost_dimer(params)
     global times;
     global measurements;

     h0 = [100 0];
     vopt = odeset('InitialStep',0.04,'MaxStep',0.04);
     %t=0 to t=1, pass parameter E2=0.3 and P4=0.1 to add to ODEs
     E2=0.3; P4=0.1;
     tspan=[0 1];
     [T, h] = ode45(@(t,y)ode_dimer_parametric(t,y,E2,P4),...
     times, h0, vopt, params);
     %t=1 to t=2, pass parameter E2=0.2 and P4=0.05 to add to ODEs
     E2=0.2; P4=0.05;
     tspan=[1 2];
     [T, h] = ode45(@(t,y)ode_dimer_parametric(t,y,E2,P4),...
     times, h0, vopt, params);
     %t=2 to t=3, pass parameter E2=0.5 and P4=0.2 to add to ODEs
     E2=0.5;P4=0.2;
     tspan=[2 3];
     [T, h] = ode45(@(t,y)ode_dimer_parametric(t,y,E2,P4),...
     times, h0, vopt, params);
     %t=3 to t=4, pass parameter E2=0.6 and P4=0.03 to add to ODEs
     E2=0.6; P4=0.03;
     tspan=[3 4];
     [T, h] = ode45(@(t,y)ode_dimer_parametric(t,y,E2,P4),...
     times, h0, vopt, params);
     %t=4 to t=5, pass parameter E2=1 and P4=0.002 to add to ODEs
     E2=1; P4=0.002;
     tspan=[4 5];
     [T, h] = ode45(@(t,y)ode_dimer_parametric(t,y,E2,P4),...
     times, h0, vopt, params);

     % residual sum of squares
     costs = sum((h - measurements).^2);
     cost = sum(costs);
```

Comment: Your `ode_dimer_parametric` takes 3 inputs and you're giving it 3. Consider something like `@(t,y)ode_dimer_parametric(t,y,[E2,P4])`

Comment: Thanks Steve,I've tried to change it, but unfortunately it didn't work. Any other suggestions? I've tried to find some info how to use events while doing optimisation of the differential equations, but i didn't manage to find any info.

Comment: You're still getting the error `Error using cost_dimer>@(t,y)ode_dimer_parametric(t,y,E2,P4) Too many input arguments.`? That doesn't relate to events. I would recommend cutting your code down to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which still exhibits the error and editing your question.